# api route not found in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel.Firstly Api.php was not initially created in routes.After creating this is my code:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


use App\Http\Controllers\Api\StudentController;

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {


    return $request->user();
}

);

Route:: get('student',[StudentController::class,'index']);

Route::fallback(function ()

{
    return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);


});
```

But when I am running php artisan route:list student is not there.If I run it in localhost it is showing 404 not found

Can you help me?

Comment: Did you also modify bootstrap/app.php to add the route configuration? `php artisan install:api` will do all the configuration for you, if you want to use Sanctum

Comment: I haven't looked at 11 yet, if you're on that, but have you checked the RouteServiceProvider's boot method is including the api.php file?

Comment: Actually, looks like it's in bootstrap/app.php if you are in fact on Laravel 11.

Comment: And of course the usual advice applies, to clear all your caches after making changes. `artisan optimize:clear`

Answer (score 1):

From the [Laravel 11 changelog](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/releases#opt-in-routing):

> The api.php and channels.php route files are no longer present by default, as many applications do not require these files. Instead, they may be created using simple Artisan commands.

Run the artisan command below to set it up.

```
php artisan install:api
```

Manually creating the `api.php` file does not actually register the routes. Running the artisan command adds an entry in your `bootstrap/app.php` file:

```
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php', // loads the routes here.
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        //
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();
```

Comment: They say they created the file themselves, and show its contents in the question.

Comment: That does not matter. Manually creating the file does not actually register the routes. Running `php artisan install:api` adds an entry to the `app.php` file in the `bootstrap` folder. This is what OP is missing.

Answer (score -2):

are you using laravel version 11? If yes, please run the `php artisan install:api` command. Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#api-routes